# The windows platform is not supported by cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

When adding the `cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore` plug-in, I was getting error when generating windows platforms via `cordova platform add windows`.

The error was like this:

> The windows platform is not supported by cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore.
>   No operation will be performed for the specified platform.

update on 14 jan 2016:
ive tried ignore the message and try to run. but i was unable to init a JSONStore collection
environment windows 10.
testing build using windows 8.1 solution

the error i got is -1 which i read is generic error.. how can i debug this?
@idanAdar

[image: error windows]

[image: error JSON Store init]

Comment: What is the version of cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore?

Comment: hi idan, 8.0.2016110713 , also tried using 8.0.2016101414, same mesage

Comment: @IdanAdar sorry, forgot to tag

Comment: I saw. It's being investigated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with cordova-windows 4.4.3,We are working on it.Meanwhile as a workaround please use the cordova-windows 4.4.2 version.

After creating the cordova project use the below command to add windows4.4.2 platform version to it.

> cordova platform add windows@4.4.2.

**UPDATE:**

This is an issue with cordova windows platform and not with cordova-plugin-mfp. This has been fixed and you can use the master version of windows platform in your project which should resolve the issue. Here is the command to use the master version

> cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows